# Podspec dependancies in local repos

Tags: cocoapods

We've made a local repository for local podspecs. In it I've put this Lua podspec, because I need 5.1.5 support. To make sure there are no name collisions, I called it Lua51. It validates fine (via "pod spec lint", so so far so good. :-)

```
-> Lua51 (5.1.5)
  The lua language (for embedding).
  pod 'Lua51', '~> 5.1.5'
  - Homepage: https://github.com/qmx/lua
  - Source:   http://www.lua.org/ftp/lua-5.1.5.tar.gz
  - Versions: 5.1.5 [mypodrepo repo]
```

Building on that, I’d like to make a podspec that uses this as a dependency. So I added "dependencies": { "Lua51": [ "~> 5.1.5"] } to the podspec for luaz, but when I do a “pod spec lint” I get

```
[!] Unable to find a specification for `Lua51 (~> 5.1.5)` depended upon by `luaz`.
```

Is there a limit on searching for dependencies in the main repo only? Or have I done something else wrong when specifying the dependancy?

Assuming that dependency is in place, how should I add the Lua51 header directory to the HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS, so that luaz will compile?

BTW, all my podspecs are in JSON notation. Here is the link for the podspecs [Lua51](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v22ewpl2vber50c/Lua51.podspec.json?dl=0) and for [luaz](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zs6wmtf0v2eqwg1/luaz.podspec.json?dl=0)

Cheers

Nik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this [is fixable](http://guides.cocoapods.org/terminal/commands.html#pod_spec_lint) by the `--sources=https://github.com/artsy/Specs` flags on the command.

I think we could definitely do a better job around explaining the problem here. Perhaps if we don't find it we could recommend using the sources flag.

Comment: Thanks Orta, that was it, works really well with the --sources flag. :-)